# linear interpolate missing values in time series

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, linear-interpolation

I would like to add all missing dates between min and max date in a `data.frame` and linear interpolate all missing values, like

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2015-10-05","2015-10-08","2015-10-09",
                                  "2015-10-12","2015-10-14")),       
                 value = c(8,3,9,NA,5))

      date value
2015-10-05     8
2015-10-08     3
2015-10-09     9
2015-10-12    NA
2015-10-14     5

      date value approx
2015-10-05     8      8
2015-10-06    NA   6.33
2015-10-07    NA   4.67
2015-10-08     3      3
2015-10-09     9      9
2015-10-10    NA   8.20
2015-10-11    NA   7.40
2015-10-12    NA   6.60
2015-10-13    NA   5.80
2015-10-14     5      5
```

Is there a clear solution with `dplyr` and `approx`? 
(I do not like my 10 line `for` loop code.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is one way. I created a data frame with a sequence of date using the first and last date. Using `full_join()` in the `dplyr` package, I merged the data frame and `mydf`. I then used `na.approx()` in the zoo package to handle the interpolation in the `mutate()` part.

```
mydf <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2015-10-05","2015-10-08","2015-10-09",
                                    "2015-10-12","2015-10-14")),       
                   value = c(8,3,9,NA,5))

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

data.frame(date = seq(mydf$date[1], mydf$date[nrow(mydf)], by = 1)) %>%
full_join(mydf, by = "date") %>%
mutate(approx = na.approx(value))

#         date value   approx
#1  2015-10-05     8 8.000000
#2  2015-10-06    NA 6.333333
#3  2015-10-07    NA 4.666667
#4  2015-10-08     3 3.000000
#5  2015-10-09     9 9.000000
#6  2015-10-10    NA 8.200000
#7  2015-10-11    NA 7.400000
#8  2015-10-12    NA 6.600000
#9  2015-10-13    NA 5.800000
#10 2015-10-14     5 5.000000
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few solutions.

**1) zoo** Convert the data frame to a zoo series and use `na.approx` with an `xout=` of sequential dates to get the final series

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(mydf)
zz <- na.approx(z, xout = seq(start(z), end(z), "day"))
```

giving:

```
> zz
2015-10-05 2015-10-06 2015-10-07 2015-10-08 2015-10-09 2015-10-10 2015-10-11 
  8.000000   6.333333   4.666667   3.000000   9.000000   8.200000   7.400000 
2015-10-12 2015-10-13 2015-10-14 
  6.600000   5.800000   5.000000
```

It may be more convenient to leave it in zoo form so you can use all the facilities of zoo but if you need it in data frame form just use

```
DF <- fortify.zoo(zz)
```

**1a) zoo/magrittr** The above could alternately be expressed as a magrittr pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
df %>% read.zoo %>% na.approx(xout = seq(start(.), end(.), "day")) %>% fortify.zoo
```

(or omit the `fortify.zoo` part if you want zoo output).

**2) base R** We can essentially do the same thing without packages like this:

```
n <- nrow(mydf)
with(mydf, data.frame(approx(date, value, xout = seq(date[1], date[n], "day"))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Another nice and short solution (using imputeTS):

```
library(imputeTS)
x <- zoo(df$value,df$date)
x <- na.interpolation(x, option = "linear")
print(x)
```

Comment: I just started using this package and it makes this kind of thing so much easier!

Answer (score 2):

I think your code would look much clear and simple if you use Forecast package.

```
library(forecast)
x <- zoo(df$value,df$date)
x <- as.ts(x)
x <- na.interp(x)
print(x)
```